# Geo Location without Permission

Tags: c#, asp.net, saas, geo

I want to obtain the geo location of users without their permission. Thus I dont want to use the javascript html5 method.

I'm more thinking of a hosted service, where we call their api and based on the users IP address they determine a rough location.

Ive been on a lot of sites that clearly do this and know roughly where your located.

Can anyone recommend a solution to this in either code or hosted solution.

Comment: I mistakenly flagged this as a duplicate, sorry!

Comment: How badly do you need for this to be accurate? I once worked in Massachusetts (USA) for a British company. Many web sites thought I was in England because we used the headquarters' IP address ranges.

Comment: Why are the answers down voted? I wish s/o had visibility of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably help you..
http://www.iplocation.net/

Comment: That will work nicely

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress(v=vs.110).aspx

HttpRequest.UserHostAddress should get you sorted. It will get the current request's IP address.

As to the physical location, I believe you'll have to pay a service for that. Any more information would be solicitation of a service, which is frowned upon.